# Onclick Save PDF and redirect to previous page php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdf

Plese pardon me My english is not good

Hello Friends I have two pages on first page i am selecting items and on second page I am showing all the selected items after that onclick of button i am generating pdf, but after generating pdf i want to redirect on previous page(first page) I have tried with both javascript/php but its not working

```
window.print();  - To print pdf


<input type="submit"  class="button" onClick="window.print();" id="btnPrint"  name="check" value="Confirm">
```

please suggest something thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history API to go back to the previous page in the history.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_back.asp

Edit:

in response to your comment:

To traverse back one in the history, but calling it as a new page rather than going back, use this instead:

```
window.location.href = document.referrer;
```

Comment: Thansx for you reply   after Going Back I want to refresh the page because selected items are coming....

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully solve it for you :)